# c++ portaudio samples distortion after conversion

Tags: c++, audio-recording, portaudio

I'm usign Portaudio 19 (with blocking i/o) to capture the voice and give it to a toolkit that will process it.
The audio format is paInt16 (i.e. signed short int) and the buffer (where samples are stored) is of type signed short int.
The toolkit input should be of type float.
I need to keep same values of the buffer in the toolkit's data structure,
but after performing the samples conversion from short to float the signal became distorted.In the image the first is the short version of the signal, the second is the float version (both on raw audio file).(http://postimg.org/image/paajkbcu9/)
Any idea?

Edit: here's the code

```
            for( int i = 0; i < d->frag_dim_in_sample;i++ )
                (*d->ready->v)(i) = float(temp->frame[i]);
```

Thinking it was a cast problem, i tried this without changes

```
for( int i = 0; i < d->frag_dim_in_sample;i++ )
                (*d->ready->v)(i) = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&temp->frame[i]);
```

Comment: Sure, the sound is screwed-up _during_ the conversion. You should edit your question to show the code you use to make the conversion. It's possibly an integer/float math error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure reinterpret_cast is not what you want here.  Btw, did you mean to use brackets around i at the left side of the equal sign rather than parentheses, e.g. (*d->ready->v)[i] rather than (*d->ready->v)(i) ?

Comment: On the left side i'm using a toolkit class and the parentheses are the indexing operator, of the class.

Comment: @Norman - hmm. The Float32 audio I've worked with (windows API) has a range of [-1.0 .. 1.0], while a short16 sample ranges from –32,768 to 32,767 . A quick research on Portaudio doesn't really help me much, dunno what it's expected format is. I'd try a test, taking the difference of ranges into account - I.e, I'd scale the output by ~32768. Either that, or have a look at the current output in a hex editor that can display info formatted as floats. - whichever was going to be quicker.

Comment: You're right, but i'm converting to float because the toolkit takes a float vector and compair it with a 16-bit acoustic model, so converting values in the [-1.0 .. 1.0 ] range, makes impossible the comparison.

Comment: @Norman - (putting an @ before someone's username ensures they get a notification of your comment). Hard to really make smart guesses without knowing what the other toolkit is, or more particularly - _how_ the comparison is performed... But getting back to your image - how do you know that the sound was distorted during the conversion? Was it by sound,or by image? Don't forget Audacity is also expecting a range of [-1.0 .. 1.0], so passing it the 'raw' converted audio is expected to produce an image just like the one you show - one with 3 values. -1, 0, 1 (all present in the int16 source)

Comment: @Norman - I should clarify that last statement - the produced image will _appear_ to be made up of samples with only 3 values, since anything other than -1, 0 and 1 will be outside the range and will be clipped. The output will naturally still contain whatever the input held - my point was that a direct 'conversion' like you've done _should_ produce an image like you show. :)

Comment: @enhzflep (i learned ;-) ) your answers made me think, so i found all the problems. First) as you say a float wav expects values between 1 and - 1. Second) some chunk were wrong aligned then some garbage were written.  So problem solved.

Comment: @Norman - great! Glad to hear you worked the problem out. Thanks for the feedback - it' helps to make trying to answer questions worthwhile.. :)